# LinkedList by Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, overriding

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.data = item
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodeCount = 0
        self.head = None #Headnode(First node of LinkedList)
        self.tail = None #Tailnode(Last node of LinkedList)
    def getAt(self, pos): #pos = index number
        if pos<=0 or pos>self.nodeCount:
            return None
        i = 1
        curr = self.head
        while i < pos:
            curr = curr.next
            i += 1
        return curr
```

This is the code of LinkedList made by Python from DS class.

I have 2 questions from this code

1. When I learned C and C++, to make "Node class", I have to make Data field and Link(Pointer) field. And I store next Node's address(pointer) at Node's Link field. So I can move to next node. But at Python code, I don't know how node class's member's 'self.next' points next node. Which one is saved at the next field?
2. I do not inherit Node class at Linked List class. But how can I use Node class's member function 'self.next' at LinkedList class when I make getAt function?

Comment: 0. Please [format](/help/formatting) your code in code blocks.
1. Python abstracts the pointers for you so you don't have to mess about with them yourself. All you need to do is assign the `Node` object of the next node to `self.next`. 2. You do not need to inherit a class to access one of it's object's members. This behavior is consistent in most programming languages, including C/C++

Comment: 0. Thanks for the formatting and sorry for my error, cause this is my first time using stackoverflow 1. sorry but what do you mean 'abstract pointers'?

Comment: "Abstract" was probably not a good word to use. I meant to say that in Python you don't need to  deal with pointers because the language takes care of all that for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of Node and LinkedList classes in Python.  The Node class has only 2 attributes: value and next. The LinkedList class only has one attribute: start. When an empty LinkedList is created, it has no start. All the interesting action occurs in the add_item_to_end() method. When the first item is added to a linked list, a node is created and assigned to start.  When the second item is added, another node is created and assigned to the previously unoccupied next of the start node. When the third, fourth, ... nodes are added, the add method begins at the start of LinkedList and goes through all consecutively linked nodes until it reaches a node that has no next, then it set the next of that node to the node being added.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value = None, next = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, start = None):
        self.start = start

    def add_item_to_end(self, item):
        my_node = Node(value=item)
        if self.start == None:
            self.start = my_node
        else:
            p = self.start
            while p.next:
                p = p.next
            p.next = my_node

    #The following method is just to visualize the linked list. 
    #It is not necessary for the functioning of the list:
    def toList(self): 
        result = []
        if self.start:
            p = self.start
            while p is not None:
                result.append(p.value)
                p = p.next
        return result

#example runs
my_ll = LinkedList()
print(my_ll.toList())
#output: []

my_ll.add_item_to_end("bread")
print(my_ll.toList())
#output: ['bread']

my_ll.add_item_to_end("milk")
print(my_ll.toList())
#output: ['bread', 'milk']
```